# How to copy specific columns using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way I can change the following code to only copy specific cells range or columsn:

For example: I have data in all columns from A to Z. I want to copy data to another sheet but I only want to copy the data from Column A, D, H and J(A2, D2, H2, J2).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim LR As Long

Me.UsedRange.Offset(1).ClearContents                'clear existing data

With Sheets("Raw - Incident Request Report")
    .AutoFilterMode = False                         'remove any prior filtering
    .Rows(1).AutoFilter                             'activate autofilter
    .Rows(1).AutoFilter 27, Criteria1:="Breached"   'filter column D for 80%+
    LR = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    'is any data visible?
    If LR > 1 Then
        .Range("AC7:AC" & LR).Copy Range("C3")      'copy any data visible to report
        .Range("D7:D" & LR).Copy Range("D3")
        .Range("I7:I" & LR).Copy Range("E3")
        .Range("K7:K" & LR).Copy Range("F3")
        .Range("T7:T" & LR).Copy Range("G3")
    Else
        Range("C3") = "No Data Found"               'if none, give that message
    End If
    .AutoFilterMode = False                         'turn off autofilter
End With

End Sub
```

---

FINAL CODE - EDITED:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim LR As Long

Me.UsedRange.Offset(17).ClearContents

With Sheets("Raw - Incident Request Report")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    LR = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("D6:AH" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:="<>"

    If LR > 1 Then
        .Range("AC7:AC" & LR).Copy
        Sheets("Tickets").Range("C17").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("D7:D" & LR).Copy
        Sheets("Tickets").Range("D17").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("I7:I" & LR).Copy
        Sheets("Tickets").Range("E17").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("K7:K" & LR).Copy
        Sheets("Tickets").Range("F17").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("T7:T" & LR).Copy
        Sheets("Tickets").Range("G17").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Else
        Range("C17") = "No Data Found"
    End If
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If ever you want to do this stuff just try start recording a new named macro perform action, stop recording. Then analyse code of what's been produced. It's the best way to learn... The you can apply stuff to your existing code,

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but try changing

```
.Range("A2:F" & LR).Copy Range("A2")
```

to

```
.Range("H2:H" & LR).Copy Range("A2")        'copy any data visible to report
.Range("D2:D" & LR).Copy Range("B2")
.Range("J2:J" & LR).Copy Range("C2")
.Range("A2:A" & LR).Copy Range("D2")
```

EDIT:

You are trying to filter on Row 1 when your filter headers are on row 6. You should also try to set the exact range to apply an autofilter on as well rather than the entire row.

```
.AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("D6:AF6").AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="Breached"
```

Also, your PasteSpecial isn't working because the syntax isn't correct. You have to Copy first, then PasteSpecial on a range.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx

Comment: That works but the problem is that I need to Call H2:H first.. So when i copy the data I want H2 to be populated in Column A1 and then D2 to be populated in Column 2 and A2 to be populated in Column 3..... When i tried to change A2:A and add it to the end it always calls A2:A before any other column. It seems it always goes in order no matter where you located A2. @joseph4tw: Is there a way we can avoid that?

Comment: @user1170376 I see. You'll have to just perform multiple copies in that case. I'll update the answer

Comment: That is working perfectly. Now, I have one last question. Is it possible to disable formatting when the data is copied to the other sheet. What happens is that whenever the data is copied it takes the formatting and I only one plain text because the other sheets has been formatted with a different design. Also, I added a criteria "Breached" so that it only pastes the row that contains breached, but for some reason it copies everything. And one mopre thing, it seems that the code does not allow undo after the code runs. I updated the code on my question. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @user1170376 to answer your "last question" lol 1) Use PasteSpecial 2) Use SpecialCells 3) you cannot undo any data the VBA macro changes to the sheet (not in Excel, at least).

Comment: I've tried searching online on how to use Paste Special and Special cells but I was not able to make it work. Using this code `.Rows(1).AutoFilter 27, Criteria1:="Breached" 'filter column AC for Breached - Text` should only show breached tickets but is not working - im asking it to filter column 27 by breached tickets. And I tried using paste special like this `.Range("D7:D" & LR).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _:=False, Transpose:=False Range("D3")` but it does not work.

Comment: I edited my main quesiton and added the code I tried using but it did not work. And instead of using SpecialCells I used `.Rows(1).AutoFilter 27, Criteria1:="Breached" 'filter column AC for Breached - Text ` which works in other workbooks but for some reason is not working on this one.

Comment: Here is the link to the file [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55305970/Daily%20Report.xlsm)

Comment: There is only one problem. I get Run-time error '1004' Auto Filter method of range class failed. Thats the message I get when I use the code I posted above (EDITED). If I check the ranges everything looks fine. I am selecting the correct ranges. When I use `.Range("D6:AF6").AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="Breached"` it works but it only selects the first one. I've tried using "D6:AC100" because in AC is where the breached ticket text is populated but it does not work. I posted a test sheet above. The original sheet has a lot more content.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55305970/Report.xlsm) to the file with the new code. The code won't work because I set the range to "D7:AC7" but if you change it to what you suggested it works but only grabs the first breached ticket

Comment: @user1170376, I see. The issue now is that the Range `D7:AC7` means that column 1 is now D and so you can't use column 29 because it doesn't exist within that range (there are only 27 columns). That's why in my edited code I changed the `Field:=24` instead of 27 like it was.

Comment: see my final code on the top. I was able to make it work with your help and another user from another forum [Link](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/921401-paste-data-from-one-sheet-to-another.html) Thank you so much!

Comment: @user1170376 that's great. Can you please mark my answer as the one that resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of your code to use arrays for the ranges and cut down on repetition. Please note, the correct answer to this post is Joseph4tw, my answer is just code advice.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim LR As Long, MyCopyRange As Variant, MyPasteRange As Variant, X As Long

Me.UsedRange.Offset(17).ClearContents

With Sheets("Raw - Incident Request Report")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    LR = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    MyCopyRange = Array("AC7:AC" & LR, "D7:DC" & LR, "I7:IC" & LR, "K7:K" & LR, "T7:TC" & LR) 'Put ranges in an array
    MyPasteRange = Array("C17", "D17", "E17", "F17", "G17")
    .Range("D6:AH" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:="<>"

    If LR > 1 Then
        For X = LBound(MyCopyRange) To UBound(MyCopyRange) 'Loop the array copying and pasting based on element in the array
            .Range(MyCopyRange).Copy
            Sheets("Tickets").Range(MyPasteRange).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Next
    Else
        Range("C17") = "No Data Found"
    End If
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim LR As Long, MyCopyRange As Variant, MyPasteRange As Variant, X As Long
Dim J as Integer

Me.UsedRange.Offset(17).ClearContents

With Sheets("Raw - Incident Request Report")
.AutoFilterMode = False
LR = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
MyCopyRange = Array("AC7:AC" & LR, "D7:DC" & LR, "I7:IC" & LR, "K7:K" & 
LR, "T7:TC" & LR) 'Put ranges in an array
MyPasteRange = Array("C17", "D17", "E17", "F17", "G17")
.Range("D6:AH" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:="<>"

      If LR > 1 Then
  
        For X = LBound(MyCopyRange) To UBound(MyCopyRange) 'Loop the array copying and pasting based on element in the array
       .Range(MyCopyRange(j)).COPY 'added the missing arrary j
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range(MyPasteRange(j)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            j = j + 1 'added
        Next
    Else
        Range("A2") = "No Data Found for this month"
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

' this code has been tested. credit still given to the above guy

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.